# Spark RDD dynamic key generator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have tab separated text file. I am just extracting key based on concatenation of array elements `keyBy(_(6).trim() + "pr" + _(0))`. My question is how can I make it generic based on comma separated index value, For ex: I want to pass comma separated index `(6,0)` with separator `pr`  and it will give concatenating key.

```
val x = rawinput.map(_.split("\t"))
  .keyBy(_(6).trim() + "pr" + _(0)) // extract key
  .flatMap{ case (k, arr) => arr.take(7).zipWithIndex.map((k, _)) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the given indices sequence to the matching array items and use `mkString` to concatenate them:

```
val indices = Seq(6, 0)
val x = rawinput.map(_.split("\t"))
  .keyBy(arr => indices.map(arr).mkString("pr")) // extract key
```

Comment: Thank you @Tzach. Suppose we have multiple separator, For Ex: `keyBy(_(6).trim() + "pr" + _(0) + "pm" +  _(0) + "pq" + _(1)) ` then how can we handle this situation?

Comment: You can sequence of _tuples_ to represent index and delimiter, something like: `val indices = Seq((6, "pr"), (0, "pm"), (1, ""))` and then in the `keyBy`: `arr => indices.map { case (i, d) => arr(i) + d }.mkString()`

Comment: You are genius @Tzach... Thanks for your help.